# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" com vuejs

Tags: vue.js, sintaxe

Estou recebendo esse erro em vários arquivos.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

O debugger diz que é arquivo .js, porém me manda para os arquivos html e mostra o erro logo na primeira linha do html, onde tem o doctype.
Não existe erro de sintaxe pois o código apenas foi copiado de um projeto já existente.

Algumas funcionalidades e os métodos dentro dos arquivos .js deixaram de funcionar.

Alguém consegue me ajudar com esse erro? Tudo que encontro é nada relacionado ao que preciso.

Segue os arquivos os quais o debugger reclama o erro:

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.inicial .btn-login').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('inicial-login');
});

$('#voltarHome').click(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('inicial-login');
});

$('.nav-img').click(function(){
    $('.nav-links').toggle('300');
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('on');
});

$('.click-sidebar').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('on');
    $('.nav-links').hide('300');
});

$('#post-categoria').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 'venda'){
        $('#vendaetroca').toggle('100');
    }
});

});
```

vue-api-register-candidate.js

```
import Form from './core/Form';
//import Axios from 'axios';

/*Os seguintes imports estão comentandos e deixados no código para possível uso futuro*/
//import Modal from './components/Modal.vue';
//import Datepicker from "./vue2-datepicker.js";

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#candidate-register',
    data: {
        form: new Form(),
        image: "./img/img-placeholder.png",
        name_image: "",
        name: "",
        name_file_video: "",
        name_file: "",
        resume_file: "",
        video_file: "",
        selectFunction: "",
        cpf: "",
        email: "",
        cellphone: "",
        state: "",
        neighborhood: "",
        city: "",
        adress: "",
        street_number: "",
        complement: "",
        hiring_type: "",
        intended_salary: "",
        description: "",
        complement: "",
        id: "",
        id_user: "",
        password: "",
        password_confirm: "",
        logged: false,
    },
    mounted() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('id') != null) {
            this.logged = true;
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem('id') != "" && localStorage.getItem('id_user')) {
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

        //Traz o candidato logado. URL de edição de candidate
        axios.post("url_aqui", {
            id: localStorage.getItem('id')
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.data);
            this.image = response.data.data.profile_image;
            this.name = response.data.data.name;
            this.cpf = response.data.data.cpf;
            this.email = response.data.data.email;
            this.cellphone = response.data.data.cellphone;
            this.state = response.data.data.state;
            this.neighborhood = response.data.data.neighborhood;
            this.city = response.data.data.city;
            this.adress = response.data.data.adress;
            this.street_number = response.data.data.street_number;
            this.complement = response.data.data.complement;
            this.hiring_type = response.data.data.hiring_type;
            this.intended_salary = response.data.data.intended_salary;
            this.description = response.data.data.description;
            this.resume_file = response.data.data.resume_file;
            this.selectFunction = response.data.data.id_function_candidate;
            this.id = response.data.data.id;
            this.id_user = response.data.data.id_user;
            this.complement = response.data.data.complement;
            this.video_file = response.data.data.video_file;

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

},
methods: {
    processForm() {
        if (this.id == "" && this.id_user == "") {
            this.form.data.name = this.name;
            this.form.data.cpf = this.cpf;
            this.form.data.email = this.email;
            this.form.data.cellphone = this.cellphone;
            this.form.data.state = this.state;
            this.form.data.neighborhood = this.neighborhood;
            this.form.data.city = this.city;
            this.form.data.adress = this.adress;
            this.form.data.street_number = this.street_number;
            this.form.data.complement = this.complement;
            this.form.data.hiring_type = this.hiring_type;
            this.form.data.intended_salary = this.intended_salary;
            this.form.data.description = this.description;
            this.form.data.name_image = this.name_image;
            this.form.data.name_file_video = this.name_file_video;
            this.form.data.name_file = this.name_file;
            this.form.data.id_function_candidate = this.selectFunction;
            this.form.data.complement = this.complement;
            this.form.data.password = this.password;
            this.form.data.password_confirm = this.password_confirm;
            this.form.data.id = null;
            this.form.data.id_user = null;

            this.form.submit("url_aqui", this.onSuccess);

        } else {

            this.form.data.name = this.name;
            this.form.data.cpf = this.cpf;
            this.form.data.email = this.email;
            this.form.data.cellphone = this.cellphone;
            this.form.data.state = this.state;
            this.form.data.neighborhood = this.neighborhood;
            this.form.data.city = this.city;
            this.form.data.adress = this.adress;
            this.form.data.street_number = this.street_number;
            this.form.data.complement = this.complement;
            this.form.data.hiring_type = this.hiring_type;
            this.form.data.intended_salary = this.intended_salary;
            this.form.data.description = this.description;
            this.form.data.name_image = this.name_image;
            this.form.data.name_file_video = this.name_file_video;
            this.form.data.name_file = this.name_file;
            this.form.data.id_function_candidate = this.selectFunction;
            this.form.data.complement = this.complement;
            this.form.data.id = this.id;
            this.form.data.id_user = this.id_user;
            this.form.data.password = this.password;
            this.form.data.password_confirm = this.password_confirm;

            this.form.submit("url_aqui", this.onSuccess);
        }

    },
    onSuccess(response) {
        try {
            if (response.data.result == true) {
                if(localStorage.getItem('id') == null){
                    alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!\nVocê será redirecionado para fazer o login.");
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }else{
                    alert("Edições salvas!");
                }


                this.form.reset();

                this.$refs.modal.configModal('Sucesso', 'Registro salvo!', 'OK', '', function () {
                    util.goBack();
                });
                this.$refs.modal.show(2500);
            } else {
                alert(response.data.msg);
                this.$refs.modal.configModal('Aviso', response.data.msg, '', 'OK');
                this.$refs.modal.show();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    //Para Salvar Imagem
    onFileChange(e, type) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        if (type == 1) {
            this.name_image = files[0].name;
        } else if (type == 0) {
            this.name_file_video = files[0].name;
        } else {
            this.name_file = files[0].name;
        }

        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(files[0], type);
    },

    createImage(file, type) {
        var image = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var vm = this;

        if (type == 1) {
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.image = e.target.result;
                this.form.data.image_b64 = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else if (type == 0) {
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.form.data.video_b64 = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.form.data.file_b64 = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    },

    backToHome() {
        if (this.id == localStorage.getItem('id')) {
            console.log("entrou no if");
            localStorage.clear();
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        } else {
            console.log("entrou no else");
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        }
    }
}
})
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Clique em [edit] e poste seu código.

Comment: Gilherme, sua pergunta tem muito pouco detalhe do problema e fica difícil de ajudar de verdade sem ficar poluindo os comentários como esse meu :D - Edite a pergunta e adicione o restante do erro, para sabermos em que arquivo foi ou se é problema de configuração de algum loader do webpack.

Comment: @fernandosavio nao tem mais nada, apenas isso mesmo. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. Recebo 3 desse ao todo, um para o arquivo vue.js:1, outro para meu script.js:1 e outro para uma api. Vou editar e colocar o código de cada um aqui para verificarem. Porém como eu disse, o projeto apenas foi importado para a estrutura do vue, antes funcionava corretamente portanto acho que não existe erro de sintaxe :s. Me deem 1 minuto para eu postar aqui